# JSC has reorganized its website. Where is the old /news/columbia information now?

Tags: nasa, history

At some point after the STS-107 failure, Johnson Space Center posted a lot of valuable material online that hadn't been publicly available before. Especially the STS Generic Flight Rules, which used to have a banner in it POSTING ON ANY ELECTRONIC FORUM IS EXPRESSLY FORBIDDEN.

The [Flight Data File page](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/flightdatafiles/index.html) is now wearing the abandonware banner
[image]like the late lamented spaceflight.nasa.gov.  Hopefully these great resources aren't going down the memory hole.

Now it appears that JSC's web site is being assimilated into the Borg-like and dumbed-down mass of "nasa.gov" Are the flight rules still available? They used to be at http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/news/columbia/fr_generic.pdf

Comment: There's always the [WayBackMachine](https://archive.org). Some of the stuff you want is archived there.

Comment: But yes, NASA has done a exceedingly good job of dumbing down nasa.gov, something that started in the previous administration.

Comment: Sadly, looks like the page itself is there, but not the linked documents. https://web.archive.org/web/20130406005211/http://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/shuttle/columbia.html

Comment: Arg, it looks like the JSC history portal is gone too. Hope I downloaded everything of interest already :(

Comment: Way back when I had a clearance I was told to stop working on an analysis project, **right now**. Using math and physics, we apparently were on the verge of stumbling upon something that was well above our clearance level. I jokingly remarked that if the DoD had its druthers, it would declare $F=ma$ to be TS:NOFORN. My supervisor not so jokingly replied "That's just about right". NASA's dumbed down web pages appear to follow that thinking.

Comment: I knew the end was near for JSC web sites when they abandoned the admittedly clunky, but well populated, spaceflight.nasa.gov for Flickr. (shakes head) Flickr!